# Using generics while trying to access sub class member

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have these objects:

```
class Order { ... }

class OrderA : Order { public double X; }

class OrderB : Order { public double X; }

class OrderC : Order { public double Y; }
```

And i want to do a method that receives any of the 3 subclasses of Order object like this:

```
private DoSomething<T>(T order) where T : Order
{
    double myValue = order is OrderA || order is OrderB ? (T)order.X : (T)order.Y;

    // DO SOMETHING MORE
}
```

But i can't compile my code because "T does not contain a definition for X..."
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
double myValue = 
    (order is OrderA) ? ((OrderA)order).X :
    (order is OrderB) ? ((OrderB)order).X :
    (order is OrderC) ? ((OrderC)order).Y;
```

However, having to do this kind of test inside a generic, kind of defeats the purpose of using generics.

You could provide different overloads of `DoSomething` to handle each case you expect to receive:

```
private DoSomething(OrderA order)
{
    double myValue = order.X;
    // DO SOMETHING MORE
}

private DoSomething(OrderB order)
{
    double myValue = order.X;
    // DO SOMETHING MORE
}

private DoSomething(OrderC order)
{
    double myValue = order.Y;
    // DO SOMETHING MORE
}
```

Then you will probably want to wrap that 'DO SOMETHING MORE' up in a private method to use as much common logic as possible.

*Alternatively*, you could create a virtual or abstract method in `Order`, like this:

```
class Order {
    public virtual double GetValue() { ... }
}

class OrderA : Order { 
    public double X; 
    public override double GetValue() { return this.X; }
}

class OrderB : Order { 
    public double X; 
    public override double GetValue() { return this.X; }
}

class OrderC : Order { 
    public double Y; 
    public override double GetValue() { return this.Y; }
}

...

private DoSomething(Order order)
{
    double myValue = order.GetValue();
    // DO SOMETHING MORE
}
```

Notice, neither solution needed to make use of generics.

Comment: I'm definitely in favor of the second approach, because polymorphism is exactly the benefit of having those `Order` subclasses in the first place.

Comment: If the OP goes with adding a `GetValue` method on the `Order` class then it's pointless for him to keep `X` and `Y` properties on child classes IMHO.

Comment: @Crono Probably true. It's unclear what those are doing there in the first place, as OP hasn't provided a very clear description of the problem. It's likely it can be refactored so that `Value` is just a property of `Order` with no need to override at all.

Comment: Also why are you suggesting both overloaded `DoSomething` methods *and* overridable `GetValue` method? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Crono I'm suggesting two alternatives. Both are valid approaches.

Comment: Ah indeed, I see it now: *either providing different*... etc. :) I definitely vote for the first alternative. IMHO it's a bit presumptuous to assume it makes sense for the OP to denature the basic `Order` class. :)

Comment: @Crono it depends on the nature of the problem, but thanks. +1 for your answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

Since `X` / `Y` members haven't been declared at the core `Order` class, the `DoSomething` method cannot possibly see them. Of course you can cast your order value to the type you want, but that defeats the purpose of using a generic method to begin with.

I personnally have a rule of thumb with generics: whenever I require casting on a generic type, **I'm most certainly doing something wrong**.

If all you need is to get the appropriate value before doing "something more", I suggest you use overloaded methods instead. These could in turn call a "core" method with appropriate arguments:

```
private void DoSomething(OrderA order)
{
    DoSomethingMore(order, order.X);
} 

private void DoSomething(OrderB order)
{
    DoSomethingMore(order, order.X);
} 

private void DoSomething(OrderC order)
{
    DoSomethingMore(order, order.Y);
} 

private void DoSomethingMore(Order order, double value)
{
    // do something more
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order classs define an abstract method and override it in each subclass. That way each class can do the job without cast the order instances. As @Crono said, that will defeats the purpose of generics.

```
//In Order class
public abstract void DoIt(){}

//In OrderSubClass class
public override void DoIt(){
  //Do Something with X or Y
}

//Client code
private void doSomething( Order theOrder){
  theOrder.DoIt();
}
```

If the processing is more complex, i recomend you to stick with template method pattern:
[Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx)